# Sign-in Sign-up form with Node+MySql Docker Container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

i want to realize a simple web-app with sign-in/sign-up form with nodejs+mysql for insert user into a db. I want to use docker container.
I'm pretty new with node, so can you give me some idea where can i start from?

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of reasources and material about it. You can just google for `dockerizing nodejs application` or similar:

Start with official ones:

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

https://github.com/docker/labs/tree/master/developer-tools/nodejs/porting/